# How do you dynamically create a array using only select columns of data in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has one worksheet as a data source and 5 other worksheets that are printable reports. The data worksheet has a range of 34 columns by 240 rows.  I need to compile a array of specific columns such as 1,3-6, 11, 14, 17-24, 29 & 34.  Then search the array row 1 for a specific category of data and then write all rows with that category, if it 1 or a 100, to another worksheet.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: Your right I took the easy road.  Everything I know in Excel has been self taught and still have no concept or understanding of arrays but I am working on it, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the push in the right direction "Gary's Student".  This is what It evolved into, which is only part 1 of 4. Sometime you just need a nudge to get the brain working.

```
Function Applications()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Traffic")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Processing Apps")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Approved Apps")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("Denied Apps")

Dim ColLast1 As Long, RowLast As Long, FullName As Long, SubDate As Long, Wants As Long, _
    PosUnit As Long, MoveInDate As Long, AppDep As Long, LSent As Long, LRec As Long, ESent As Long, _
    ERec As Long, SSent As Long, SRec As Long, SexOff As Long, Crim As Long, Correct As Long, _
    PreApp As Long, Corp As Long, FU1Date As Long, FU1Note As Long, StatusCode As Long

    With ws1
    ColLast1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, ColLast1))
            StatusCode = .Find("Code").Column
            FullName = .Find("Full Name").Column
            SubDate = .Find("Submit").Column
            Wants = .Find("Wants").Column
            PosUnit = .Find("Punit").Column
            MoveInDate = .Find("MIDate").Column
            AppDep = .Find("App/Dep").Column
            LSent = .Find("LLSent").Column
            LRec = .Find("LLRecieved").Column
            ESent = .Find("EMSent").Column
            ERec = .Find("EMRecieved").Column
            SSent = .Find("ShanSent").Column
            SRec = .Find("ShanRecieved").Column
            SexOff = .Find("SO").Column
            Crim = .Find("Criminal").Column
            Correct = .Find("Corrections").Column
            PreApp = .Find("Prelim").Column
            Corp = .Find("SentToCorp").Column
            FU1Date = .Find("AppFU1Date").Column
            FU1Note = .Find("AppFU1").Column
        End With
    End With

    k = 1
    ReDim data(1 To (RowLast), 1 To 19) As Variant

    For i = 10 To RowLast

        Select Case ws1.Cells(i, StatusCode).Value

            Case "W"

                AppWorking = Array(FullName, SubDate, Wants, PosUnit, MoveInDate, AppDep, LSent, LRec, _
                            ESent, ERec, SSent, SRec, SexOff, Crim, Correct, PreApp, Corp, FU1Date, FU1Note)

                        j = 1

                        For Each A In AppWorking

                                data(k, j) = ws1.Cells(i, A).Value

                            j = j + 1

                        Next A

                        k = k + 1

        End Select

    Next i

    x = UBound(data, 1) - LBound(data, 1) + 1
    y = UBound(data, 2) - LBound(data, 2) + 1

    Range("ProcessingDataField").Resize(x, y) = data
    Sheet7.Activate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to create the array:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ary = Array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 34)
    ReDim Data(1 To 240, 1 To 17) As Variant
    j = 1
    For Each a In ary
        For i = 1 To 240
            Data(i, j) = Cells(i, a).Value
        Next i
        j = j + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```